# can't get specific query-replace-regexp in emacs to work

Tags: regex, replace, emacs

I have a block of code as such, and I am trying to modify it with query-replace-regexp in emacs.

```
fz.D(1,:) = Dcen;                
fz.vol(1,:) = (4/3)*pi*((fz.D(1,:)/2).^3);          
fz.POC(1,:) = Ac*fz.vol(1,:).^bc;         
fz.w(1,:) = cw*fz.D(1,:).^eta;

% size - bin edges
fzl.D(1,:) = Dlim;
```

I want it to look as so:

```
fz.D(ind,:) = fz.D(1,:);                
fz.vol(ind,:) = fz.vol(1,:);          
fz.POC(ind,:) = fz.POC(ind,:);
```

and so fourth.

I tried to enact this change with the following, but it doesn't seem to work

> query-replace-regexp
>    `\(*\)(1,:) = *; -> \1(k,:) = \1(1,:);`

But that seems to do nothing.

Any suggestions about how I should fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know emacs, but your regular expression needs to use `.*` for the 'match any length substring' operation:

> query-replace-regexp `\(.*\)\((1,:)\) = .*; -> \1(ind,:) = \1\2;`

(This also makes use of a second `\(\)` group to avoid repeating the part of the pattern that you want to repeat in the replacement text)

The reason:

In regular expressions, `*` is a postfix operator that matches *"0 or more of the previous item"*.  When found with no previous item, it matches a plain `*`.  Thus, your expression `\(*\)(1,:) = *;` matched the exact text `*(1,:) =` followed by 0 or more spaces followed by `;`.  You want to use `.*` to "match anything", as this matches 0 or more `.` items (where `.` matches any one non-end-of-line character).

Comment: Ah, that's a clever and concise solution. Also, thanks for adding the reason. These regexps are starting to make more sense to me now.